# Git stash list merge push

Tags: git, git-stash

I am getting dizzy with this simple thing.

```
sudo git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on main: 03d5e72 14
stash@{1}: WIP on main: 03d5e72 14
stash@{2}: WIP on main: 03d5e72 14
stash@{3}: WIP on main: 03d5e72 14
stash@{4}: WIP on main: 03d5e72 14

sudo git commit -m "main"
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean

sudo git merge
Already up to date.

sudo git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Can I know how to push all git changes ?
When I checked at github website there is no changes and no new commits

Comment: What do you mean with "all git changes"? You want to push all 5 stashes in one commit?

Answer (score 2):

You have no commits on your `main` that you can send to `origin` to be new commits on *their* `main` because all the commits you have on your `main` are already on their `main`.

Those five stash commits<sup>1</sup> are *not on any branch*.  You can't push stashes,<sup>2</sup> and you shouldn't as they're not everyday commits (see footnote 1).  To push a stash, you should in general turn it into a branch, e.g., using `git stash branch`.  You can then have normal everyday commits that you *can* push as branches, or you can merge or cherry-pick those commits into existing branches as appropriate.

In general, I recommend that those new to Git *avoid* `git stash`.  All it does is make some slightly wacky commits that are not on any branch at all.  This makes the stashes hard to use.  If you make *normal* commits on a *branch*, they're normal and are easy to find and use.  Just make a new branch (if necessary / appropriate), and make the commit.  Learn how to use `git rebase -i` with unpublished (not-yet-pushed, or pushed-to-private-use-only branches) commits to re-shuffle them and re-combine them into the commits you would have made earlier if you had known *before* doing your work, what you now know *after* doing the work.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, each stash consists of at least two, and sometimes three, commits.  One of the two-or-three commits has the form of a merge commit, but the other commit(s) aren't the kind of commits you'd normally make before making a merge commit.  So Git tools that deal with merge commits will misinterpret the merge commit in a stash.

In particular, this means you should not use `git show stash` but rather `git stash show` to view the current top-of-stash-stack stash.  It's very easy to reverse these two words by mistake, and when you do, the stash often appears to be *empty*.  It's not—it's just Git being confused by this "looks like a stash, smells like a stash, tastes like a stash, good thing we didn't use it as a stash" <s>joke<sup>3</sup></s> commit.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, you *can* push them.  However, you must make up a refname on the server side—a branch name—after which the Git on the other side will be *really* confused.  In general, don't do this.  Note that the `git stash` code can deal with these if you do; it's just inconvenient.

<sup>3</sup>[The very word *stash* just seems to invite old Cheech and Chong material.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY7ZX6ngOSs)